# "В основном" - точно невводное?

Tags: пунктуация

На http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_93 написано, что невводное, только наречие, а на [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/в_основном](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC) написано, что может быть вводным, если стоит в начале предложения.

В основном, мы делаем то, что хотим делать.

Answer (score 4):

1) В основном - это "главным образом", семантика для вводного значения подходящая. **Тем не менее обособляется слово редко,** то есть, как правило, он выполняет функцию наречия в роли обстоятельства.

2) Чаще встречается обособление **в середине предложения,** когда его структура позволяет интонационно выделить вводное слово, занимающее удобную для обособления позицию, например:

Вся высшая нервная деятельность связана, **в основном,** с корой головного мозга.
Сама, **в основном,** молчала, может, слушала, а может ― и не очень. 
Леса спускаются до самого моря, занимая примерно 82% территории, и представлены, **в основном,** смешанным широколиственным лесом колхидского типа.

3) В начале предложения обособление  обнаруживается редко (его трудно выделить интонационно, сделать паузу):

**В основном** деньги идут к нам из местного бюджета. **В основном** сокращение издержек произошло вследствие сокращения численности персонала.

4) В этом предложении "в основном" обособлено (но решение не кажется удачным): **В основном,** возрождение любви к древней иконописи носит подражательный, характер.

ВЫВОД

**Чтобы выражение было вводным, необходимо наличие двух условий:** А) подходящей для вводного слова тематики; Б) **подходящей для обособления позиции в структуре данного предложения.**

Приводимые источники не стоит рассматривать как некий абсолют, дающий единственно правильный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

В основном, мы делаем то, что хотим делать. -предложение имеет двойной смысл. Можно понять:1. "Самое главное, мы делаем, что хотим делать"-вводное.

2.Преимущественно (чаще всего)мы делаем то, что хотим делать.-наречие,не вводное.

"В основном" -как? в какой мере? синонимы- в главном, преимущественно, больше всего, чаще всего - это наречие образа и степени действия, не вводное слово.

Значение "главным образом" не свидетельствует о том, что это вводное слово.Само сочетание "главным образом" является вводным только в значении «самое главное», например: Статью нужно исправить и, главным образом, дополнить свежим материалом. В значении же «преимущественно», «в основном», «больше всего» указанное сочетание не является вводным, например: Он добился успеха главным образом благодаря своему трудолюбию; Мне нравится в нем главным образом его искренность.
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-alphabet -полный список вводных слов. "В основном" там нет.В литературном блоге редактора и корректора Раисы Аркадьевны Пирагис есть список ложных вводных слов, вот там сочетание имеется.
http://www.litsite.ru/2011/01/13/loznye-vvodnye-slova/

Таким образом, можем сказать: В основном своём значении сочетание "в основном" не является вводным словом, это наречие со значением "преимущественно", но иногда бывает авторское употребление наречия в значении "основное, самое главное, что хочу сказать", это позволяет сделать современная тенденция к сокращению текста, вот тогда наречие превращается в вводное со значением последовательности мыслей (что главное, что неглавное), как и "главным образом" и "главное".