# "В первую очередь" и "в основном" — выделять?

Tags: пунктуация

*Мы говорим в первую очередь о фильме и его качестве в основном с кинематографической точки зрения.*

Нужно ли здесь обособить "в первую очередь" и "в основном"?

Comment: Вам, возможно, стоит обратить внимание на уже обсуждавшийся вопрос: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417248/%D0%92-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5

Answer (score 1):

Мы говорим в первую очередь о фильме и его качестве в основном с кинематографической точки зрения.

**Стилистика предложения не совсем корректна**, это касается прежде всего порядка слов. "В первую очередь и в основном" – это практически одно и то же. Кроме того, оба сочетания являются наречиями (по словарю-справочнику  "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации") и поэтому обычно не обособляются.

**Предлагаемый вариант:** О фильме и его качестве мы говорим прежде всего с кинематографической точки зрения.

Comment: А по-моему, это предложение следует понимать так: Мы говорим в первую очередь о фильме и его качестве. Говорим об этом в основном с кинематографической точки зрения. --- Предлагаемый вариант: Мы говорим в первую очередь о фильме и его качестве, в основном  - с кинематографической точки зрения.